# Wordpress resizes image to the same size as uploaded

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I am writing a theme which uses different image sizes.

Here are my targeted sizes as they are set up in under Settings > Media in WP Admin:

[image]

Here is the functions.php code for the thumbnail support:

```
$THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 320;
$MEDIUM_SIZE = 460;
$LARGE_SIZE = 1366;


if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) { 
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

  set_post_thumbnail_size(        $THUMBNAIL_SIZE,  9999);
  add_image_size( 'medium-size',  $MEDIUM_SIZE,  9999 ); 
  add_image_size( 'large-size',  $LARGE_SIZE, 9999 );
}
```

So, as you can see, the sizes are 320px wide, 460px wide and 1366px wide.

The problem is, when I upload a 1366px wide image it uploads the original file and additionally creates 320px, 460px **and 1366px** resized images.

E.g.

**UPLOAD**:

- someimage.jpg (which is 1366px wide)

---

**OUTPUT** (in /uploads/2015/08/)

- someimage.jpg
- someimage-1366x937.jpg
- someimage-460x316.jpg
- someimage-320x220.jpg

What I can see is that the autocreated someimage-1366x937.jpg is compressed, which I am not really anticipating.

---

In my previous experience if the uploaded image had the same size as the largest specified size, it did not create a duplicate.

I don't need these duplicated images with the same width as the original upload, they are just wasting storage space.

I am using Wordpress 4.3. No plugins are added yet, so it's definitely something that is the Wordpress core is doing, I haven't experienced this before updating version 4.3 (I used a version 4.0 before and picked up developing WP again  after 4.3 came out.

---

UPDATE:

Here is my **image editing process**.

I always resize the image to the largest size needed.
Some posts need 1366px wide images, some only need a 460px wide image.

Whatever scenario applies, I want Wordpress to take the image I upload and not to recreate a compressed duplicate of it. Additionally, it has to create all the smaller sizes.

This means:

- 1366px upload --> create 460px and 320px
- 460px upload ---> create 320px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uploading images the same size as the large size in your WordPress installation, then set your **Large size** to 0x0 in Settings -> Media or remove this line:

```
add_image_size( 'large-size',  $LARGE_SIZE, 9999 );
```

**EDIT #1:**

Try to add this filter to delete the original image:

```
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'delete_fullsize_image');
function delete_fullsize_image($metadata) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $full_image_path = trailingslashit($upload_dir['basedir']) . $metadata['file'];
    $deleted = unlink($full_image_path);

    return $metadata;
}
```

It will delete the original image after upload and keep only the generated ones.

**EDIT #2:**

Check these two plugins (untested), they might help you do it automatically:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/original-image-handler/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/delete-original-image/

Comment: The problem is that occassionally I upload 460px wide images too. So I need a solution that handles resizing for all possible sizes.

Comment: What I also see is that I had no problem using this code on WP 4.0, and suddenly this issue popped up.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE seciton in my post.

Comment: Do you really have to add the code in functions.php file? It basically does the same as the settings in your **Media** section. I think your problem is because you don't specify a fixed height, that's why WordPress duplicates your images. Regarding your last comment, WordPress 4.3 changed lots of stuff in the media part of the code.

Comment: I have removed the add_image_size() and set_post_thumbnail_size() lines. The Media Library still creates duplicates.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, it solves the problem, but I need to test if it works with other image related code I am using.

Comment: Let me know how it works. I want to implement the same behaviour in a site I'm developing now and I need to keep disk space at a minimum.

Comment: OK, I'll give some feedback in due time.