# How to delete original image file after upload and resize

Tags: images, uploads, post-thumbnails

When I upload an image named `image.jpg`, Wordpress creates `image-150x150.jpg`.

How can I delete `image.jpg` and keep just the `image-150x150.jpg` in `function.php`, because I want to optimize my disk space on the hosting plan.

Comment: Did you have taken a look at this? [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199495).

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help a lot.